# how to implement prevention to XXE or XSS attacks on wso2 IS or apim

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

i have security problem in wso2 identity studio 5.10,

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40239

(xxe and xss, problem is solved in 5.1 by implementing XML Parsers
to detect malicious scripts or entities on XML messages' DTD)

For exemplify:

```
<!DOCTYPE root
<!ENTITY foo SYSTEM "file:///c:/windows/win.ini">
]>
...
<in>&foo;</in>[
```

https://wso2.com/technical-reports/wso2-secure-engineering-guidelines

2.4 A4 - XML External Entity (XXE)

mentions that this could have been prevented by adding a **DocumentBuilderFactory (DOM Parser)** and **XMLInputFactory (Stax Parser)**
if so in where, should i implement those

if not, what should i do?

where does WSO2 do its XML parsing?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, the particular [issue](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/40239) you have pointed is already resolved.

The XML parsers in the product should be strong enough to mitigate the XXE issues. If you have faced any security issue, please report the issue as mentioned in [here](https://wso2.com/security).